# How to find second large date in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have items in A column and dates in B column I need the second largest date in column D if item's name in Column is same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDTRZ.png)
I tried large with with which gave me 0 as a result

Comment: Hi, can you  share a copy of your spreadsheet (senstive data erased) so we have some data to work with?

Comment: HI, have attached a image of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the item to match is in C2 and the data is in A:B, try

```
=index(sort(filter(B:B, A:A=C2), 1, 0), 2)
```

Change range(s) to suit and see if that helps?